Querying Variant Typed Nested JSON Object Arrays in Apache Doris
I'm storing my semi structured data in Apache Doris and I wonder that is there any way to query the data in the way I want. For example I have a data like below;
{
  "eventId": 1,
  "firstName": "Name1",
  "lastName": "Surname1",
  "body": {
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "number": "5550219210",
        "type": "GSM",
        "callLimit": 5
      },
      {
        "number": "02124713252",
        "type": "HOME",
        "callLimit": 3
      },
      {
        "number": "05550219211",
        "callLimit": 2
        "type": "WORK"
      }
    ]
  }
}

The table that I created in Doris is;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event (
    eventId VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    body VARIANT NULL
)

I want to find the count of records that has more than 1 ('GSM' typed 'phoneNumbers' object and callLimit > 2) in their body.
I can do this in Apache Druid with below query;
select 
  count(*) 
from 
  (
    SELECT count(*) cnt
    FROM 
      "event" CROSS 
      JOIN UNNEST(
        json_query_array(body, '$.phoneNumbers')
      ) AS phoneNumber 
    where 
       json_value(phoneNumber, '$.type') = 'GSM' and json_value(phoneNumber, '$.callLimit') > 2
  ) as sq 
where sq.cnt > 1

I can do this in Apache Pinot with below query;
select 
  count(*) 
from 
  event e 
where 
  (
    select 
      count(*) 
    from 
      event e2 
    where 
      e2.eventId = e.eventId 
      and JSON_MATCH(
        body, '"$.phoneNumbers[*].type" = ''GSM'''
      ) 
      and json_extract_scalar(
        body, '$.phoneNumbers[*].callLimit', 
        'INT', 0
      ) > 2
  ) > 1

I can do this in TimeScaleDB with below query;
SELECT 
  count(*) 
FROM 
  event 
WHERE 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*) 
    FROM 
      jsonb_array_elements(body -> 'phoneNumbers') as phone_numbers 
    WHERE 
      phone_numbers ->> 'type' = 'GSM' 
      AND (phone_numbers ->> 'callLimit'):: int > 2
  ) > 1;

But I can't run this logic in Apache Doris. Apache Doris currently seems lacks extensive support for complex JSON operations directly within SQL queries.
Am I missing something? Is there any way for this?

This nesting is expected to be supported next month (2.1.5 expected) and currently only available as json, using json syntax, thank for your attention.
